# directory api - get users using orgName

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I have four sub-organizations defined. (/AdminOrg, /subOrgA, /SubOrgB, /subOrgA/SubOrgAA)

my directory.orgunits.list query return below data. I store the return array in a variable called orgUnits[]:

http://pastebin.com/Kzud6SAq

I have 4 users in my organization. one in each sub-organization. the users.list return below data:

http://pastebin.com/6ttSgDSe

**I am trying to get no. of users within an organization (without including sub organizations in them)**

Option 1:
The query directory.users.list.query("orgUnitPath=/subOrgA") includes users from sub organization (/subOrgA/SubOrgAA) too and does not meet my needs.

Option 2:
I tried the query directory.users.list.query("orgName=orgUnits[]->name"). It queries for users[]->organizations[]->name. And this field is null by default. It does not get populated with orgUnits[]->name.

My questions are

1. How to populate users.organizations[].name?
2. Is there any way I can get users within an organization without including sub-organizations in them

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it isn't possible to search for users within an orgUnit not including sub-orgs. The `orginations` field in the Users resource, as well as the `orgName`, `orgTitle`, `orgDepartment`, `orgDescription`, 
`orgCostCenter` query parameters, refer to a completely separate set of data that appears to be used by the API only. Only the `orgUnitPath` field and query parameter operate on the organizations visible within the Google Apps Admin Console.