# Query Google Admin User directory for multiple parameters

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I'm trying to query Google Admin User directory on two parameters: `name` and `orgName`. I have tried several variations of the below, which does not work:

```
  var userList = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
    customer: 'my_customer',
    maxResults: 100,
    query: 'name:david AND orgName=hotel',
    viewType: 'domain_public',
    projection: 'full'
  }).users;
```

... but I think it illustrates what I'm trying to do. My questions are:

1) Is this possible?

2) If I might push my luck, is it possible to query organization location? (I didn't see anything like this in the documentation...)

Have already consulted https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users, did not find anything there.

Comment: Based from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977562) by a Googler, it is not possible to search for users within an `orgUnit` not including sub-orgs. The orginations field in the Users resource, as well as the `orgName`, `orgTitle`, `orgDepartment`, `orgDescription`,  `orgCostCenter` query parameters, refer to a completely separate set of data that appears to be used by the API only. Also, If you didn't find the type of query in the docs, then it means that it is not currently supported. Try to file a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?) if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query does not support AND or OR operators, only one search term is allowed.

I'd suggest querying on the more specific (probably name) field and then filtering locally on the additional fields. So in other words, `query=name:david` and then look for hotel in the `orgName` field locally.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I was afraid that it wouldn't be possible to query two terms, will have to filter results some other way.

Answer (score 0):

The query now supports only AND operator.

> Multiple clauses are separated by whitespace and are implicitly joined
>   by an AND operator.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users